# Multiple object tracking using radar data and extended kalman filter

Tags: matlab, object, tracking, kalman-filter

thanks in advance.
I am new to the multiple object tracking field. So, I have been working on this for a couple of days. I have developed my first version of a single object tracker using an extended Kalman filter. I am estimating position, velocity by assuming a constant acceleration model. Now my question is how can I convert the existing model for multiple objects tracking. The main problem is I am using radar data. So, I am not able to get the references for developing the tracker. So, One good example or steps to achieve can help me in understanding the concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question depends on a lot of things. For example, how much control and knowledge do you have over the whole system? If you know how many targets you need to track you can add all of them to the Kalman Filter state and for every measurement you perform data association to find out to which object a given measurement belongs. An easy association metric would be nearest neighbor.

If you don't know how many targets there will be you will want to implement a track management where each target you are tracking represents a track and you can model birth and death probabilities of targets.

Multi Target Tracking is a vast field and if you want to have an in-depth mathematical introduction I would recommend the 2015 survey paper "**Multitarget Tracking**" by Ba-Ngu Vo *et al*. You should be able to find a preprint pdf online.

If you are looking more for a lightweight tutorial I would assume it should be possible to find some tutorial or example code online where to start. As mentioned in the first paragraph, nearest neighbor association for a fixed amount of objects might be a good first step.

Comment: Thanks, I have gone through the paper. I have a doubt, how can I find the standard deviations i.e for covariance matrices.

Comment: It depends on your system. If you are simulating the data you should have some Guassian distributions for your measurements and process. You can use the standard deviations you used in simulation for the Kalman Filter. If you are looking at real data you can take a guess and try out which values work. E.g. if your sensor gives you range in meters and angle in radian, take a guess or estimate how much the measurements vary from the true value and set the standard deviation to a value that is a bound for 68% of the values.

Comment: So if about two third of your values are within 0.5m of your true target, your standard deviation is 0.5m. Square to get the variance. The covariance values (off-diagonals) are way harder to estimate correctly so you can assume no covariance of the different measurement values and set them to 0. I hope this information helps you. As I said Multi Target Tracking alone is a vast field and tracking overall is immense. If you have more doubts about how to setup your Kalman Filter correctly you might want to make a new question so this one doesn't get too broad.

Comment: Thank you, for the answer. This is the last question. In simulated data, I have given the Velocity of an object (Vx, Vy). But in real-time radar data, I am getting range, azimuth, doppler, ego velocity, SNR, and clutter image format for each scan. So, how can I input the velocity of object using the above data? Is there any relation between doppler and velocity of an object. If so how can we find the Vx and Vy of the object that is moving?. If you have any references or links please share me along with your answer.

Comment: I'm not sure what measurement your radar gives you as "doppler", the radars I have worked with up to now already output the cartesian or radial velocity. You definitely can get cartesian velocity vectors from the doppler velocity, I'm just not sure what the easiest approach would be in your case. Maybe take a look at http://www.csd.uwo.ca/faculty/barron/PAPERS/ijist2005.pdf since the title sounds like it would be what you need. Other than that you could also just give position measurements and let the filter estimate velocity itself.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Malefitz. I will try calculating the velocity based on the distance change of the object.